# How do I use RxJS to post transactions such that the next request waits for the previous one complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have a list of about 2000 transactions to post to a back-end. I want to make a request to POST the first transaction, wait for that request to complete, then move the next and so on, until I have exhausted the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `concatMap` or `exhaustMap`

`concatMap` - will call first API and will proceed to the next API only if first API call will be completed

**All calls in `concatMap` called strictly in order**

```
const { from, of } = require("rxjs");
const { concatMap } = require("rxjs/operators");

const transId = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

const postAPI = (id) => of({ id, status: "success" });

from(transId)
  .pipe(concatMap((id) => postAPI(id)))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: This works. What if I want to update two lists, one for successfully posted transactions and another for failed transactions?

Comment: not sure if I get it correcrly, if API is failed - need to add error Handler - `const postAPI = (id) => of({ id, status: "success" }).pipe(catchError(e=> of({id, status: "failed"})));` . in subscribe you will get transaction one by one you can do there whaever you want, or we can create one array of all transuction - to use `toArray()` - `.pipe(concatMap((id) => postAPI(id)), toArray())` - in this case in subscribe you will one one emited array with all transactions - you can create 2 arrays using filter => `.subscribe(data => {let success = data.filter(i => i.status === 'success'); //...})`